# If I have an XSS protection solution, does it cause chrome auditor to become disabled?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, xss

chrome says(on XSS attacks): "The auditor was enabled as the server did not send an 'X-XSS-Protection' header.";
does it mean if there be any xss protection header, the auditor will be disabled? 
and imagine if that security solution has a big XSS flaw, which auditor knows it but since the website has an XSS protection header, it will not do anything...
anyway, I dont trust auditor for xss protection but I'm curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more like the auditor is enabled by default without the header, but with the header you can control whether it's enabled or disabled.

With `X-XSS-Protection:0` the auditor will be disabled, and with `X-XSS-Protection:1` or `X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block` the auditor will be enabled.

The auditor's probably going to be removed soon anyway as it hasn't been very reliable. See: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/xss-auditor